# iPhone:Can 3.1.2 built iPhone app installable on 3.0/3.1 devices?

Tags: iphone

I have built an iPhone app with 3.1.2 SDK.

1. Can it be able to deploy on my iPhone 3.0 or 3.1 device using the same provisional profile using Xcode?
2. If i submit that app which built with 3.1.2 SDK, will it be able to install on iPhone 3.0 or 3.1 version users through AppStore?
   If not, how can advertise that my app can be installed on iPhone 3.0, 3.1 and 3.1.2 as well during submitting it in AppStore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the version of the SDK that you develop with determines the minimum version of the device that you will deploy to. So, unless you need any of the 3.1, or 3.1.2 features then just deploy to the store using the 3.0 SDK.

Comment: Thank you.One more question is that,i already submitted an app which built with 3.1.2 SDK,but not having specially any of 3.1.2 SDK features.It is also available on AppStore now.I want to build that with 3.0 SDK and want to resubmit it.In this case, my question here are, 1.If i resubmit the same application but built with different SDK, resubmission will take again time to be visible in AppStore?(or)it will be available immediately? 2.If i resubmit the same App,the existing one will be there in AppStore till it overwrites with new version App?(or)it will be like fresh submission?

Comment: Every time that you submit the app, it is treated as a new submission. Sometimes, that new submission might replace an app that is already in the store. You existing app will remain in place until it is replaced by the new (recompiled) app.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood from your answer is that, i can not remove only my previous app binary and replace with new binary if i want to re-submit the same app. There is no Edit logic for Binary. I'm not really understand one thing is, how the existing app remains till new app submission reviewed? How the existing app knows the same app is the newly updated and submitted?

Comment: When you submit your application it has the application ID associated with it. That is how they know to replace the app. And you will need to bump the version number so that they know that it is a new version of the app... the fact that it is only a recompile is not something that they can determine, or care about, so you will still go through the normal review process.